# Android C# set OnClick Layout Position on TopMost in ScrollView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i have an xml with ScorrView like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:Text="Text1"
                android:id="@+id/Text1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:Text="Text1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Text1"
                android:id="@+id/Text2" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:Text="Text1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Text2"
                android:id="@+id/Text3" />         
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

now i want to make if click Text2 then ScrollView has position Text2 on the TopMost of The screen, then if i Click on Text3 it will make ScrollView has Text3 at the top. is it possible and how?

```
default
//x
Text1
Text2
Text3
//z

OnClick Text2
Text1 hidden, visible if scroll
//x
Text2
Text3
//z
```

im trying add RequestFocus() and not working, also TextView2.ScrollTo(0, 0) only move Scroll position to 0 not focusing on TextView2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll the `ScrollView` to the specific position in the code behind, for your scenario, you can for example code like this:

```
public ScrollView scview;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

    scview = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollView1);

    TextView tv1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1);
    TextView tv2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2);
    TextView tv3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text3);

    tv1.Click += Tv_Click;
    tv2.Click += Tv_Click;
    tv3.Click += Tv_Click;
}

private void Tv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tv = sender as TextView;
    var yoffset = tv.Top;
    scview.ScrollTo(0, yoffset);
}
```

But to be clear, [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) can only be scrolled when its content is larger than the physical display, so for your case, if your scroll has a height of `match_parent` and you have only three `TextView`, then it cannot be scrolled. And if I change the height to 100dp here,  click on `Text2` will make the `ScrollView` scroll to it, but if I then click on `Text3`, the `ScrollView` won't scroll cause it is already reach the end, the topmost item will still be `Text2`, this is by design.